# Limit Scribble to numbers only

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a way to give Scribble a heads up that I'm expecting numbers only?

I have the TextField `.keyboardType` modifier set to `.numberPad` but when I use scribble to write a value it struggles with the number '11'.  Sometimes it gets 1, or 1l, etc.

I'd like it to default to producing only integers.

[image: Filling out text boxes with scribble, unable to understand 11]

Comment: What is Scribble?

Comment: Are you talking about the watchOS keyboard input method scribble?

Comment: Talking about ipad https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscribbleinteraction